# Как скрыть кнопки на изображении от яндекса?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добавила изображение, а при наведений на него отображаются лишние кнопки с поиском по картинке, добавлением в закладки. Как можно убрать это?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, но Яндекс не дал возможность "вешать" на картинки что-то для того, чтобы данные кнопки не выводились на каких-то изображениях на ваших сайтах.

Если не требуется взаимодействия с изображением (клик мышью по нему), то можно использовать [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) и тогда эти кнопки не появятся.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках Яндекс Браузера снимите галочки с чекбокс.[image: Если убрать три галочки с чекбокс то отключите полностью меню.]